# How to ignore x-max-priority when using NServiceBus with RabbitMQTransport

Tags: rabbitmq, nservicebus

I'm trying to figure out a way to migrate from an existing homegrown wrapper around RabbitMQ to NServiceBus.
The current obstacle is that the wrapper creates queues with the "x-max-priority" setting set to "9". NSB does currently not support [priority queues](https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus.RabbitMQ/issues/156) which is fine since the wrapper never uses the priority anyway.
Unfortunately NSB can't connect to queues created by the wrapper and fails with the following error:

```
Unhandled exception. RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.OperationInterruptedException:
The AMQP operation was interrupted: 
AMQP close-reason, initiated by Peer, code=406, text='PRECONDITION_FAILED - inequivalent arg 'x-max-priority' for queue 'xxxxxxx' in vhost '/':
received none but current is the value '9' of type 'signedint'', classId=50, methodId=10
```

Updating the wrapper would solve that issue for new queues. But recreating all the existing  queues would mean deleting thousands of queues at hundreds of customer sites. So that's not really an option.

Is there a way to tell NSB to use this setting when it tries to connect to existing queues and just don't do anything with it?

Comment: Hey Sebastian, I'm a developer at Particular Software, makers of NserviceBus. I understand that migrating that many queues is an issue. Would you be open to set up a call and figure out how to best deal with this? Can you email us at support@particular.net? Please let us know the region you're in so we can connect you with developers closest to you. I am in The Netherlands myself.

Comment: Hi @DennisvanderStelt, I got it working with a customized `RoutingTopology` and a custom serializer. Both parts can talk to each other (at least in the simplest possible scenario). Thanks for your willingness to help. I will contact Particular when I make the step from PoC to first iteration

Comment: Hi @sebastian-weber. Good to hear you've solved your issue. We're very keen on helping out new (or potential) customers, especially with a PoC and/or design. So if you're up for it, let us know. Happy to help out!